# Razor Inline code generating Compiler Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to dynamically set the content of a cell using the KendoGrid Content Template and inline Razor but I am getting all sorts of errors.

```
"<table><tr>" + 
"<td style='color:yellow; width:200px;height:13px;padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;text-align:center;' class='audiogrid'>" +
@{
   @if ((int)TempData["MediaTypeId"] == 1) { 
      @"<audio id='a1' src='#: MediaLocation #' controls='controls' preload='auto' autobuffer><embed height='26' autostart = 'false' type = 'audio/mpeg' width='290' src='#: MediaLocation #'></audio>" +
   }
   else{
     @"&nbsp; #: Description # " +
   }
}
"</td>" +
"</tr></table>"
```

The above code throws an error: CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ at the first instance of the @ sign.

I don't understand why or what this error means. According to the rules of using Razor in MVC4, my syntax should work. Did a little research to be sure and found the syntax to be accurate [here](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/08/mvc-4-razor-view-engine-syntax.html)
But I tried a variation that included a string after the @ as the error suggested and that I figured should work as well:

```
"<table><tr>" + 
"<td style='color:yellow; width:200px;height:13px;padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;text-align:center;' class='audiogrid'>" +
@if ((int)TempData["MediaTypeId"] == 1) { 
    @"<audio id='a1' src='#: MediaLocation #' controls='controls' preload='auto' autobuffer><embed height='26' autostart = 'false' type = 'audio/mpeg' width='290' src='#: MediaLocation #'></audio>" +
    }
    else{
          @"&nbsp; #: Description # " +
    }
"</td>" +
"</tr></table>"
```

This time I get Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected at the same line that the @ first appears in my code.

I've also tried some other variations but none of them seem to work. 
What am I doing wrong or missing here? :-(

Basically the control in the cell should change based on the media type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is not some sort of string concatenating syntax. You specify the html tags and C# code, and the Razor engine writes them to the client.

Inside an `@{` block (or any other code block), you can use C# statements. There's no need for an extra @.

Inside the `@if` (or any other code block), you can use html tags. No need to prepend them with an @.

Inside the `else` block, use `@:` to output html without an html tag.

```
<table><tr>
<td style='color:yellow; width:200px;height:13px;padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;text-align:center;' class='audiogrid'>
@{
   if ((int)TempData["MediaTypeId"] == 1) { 
      <audio id='a1' src='#: MediaLocation #' controls='controls' preload='auto' autobuffer><embed height='26' autostart = 'false' type = 'audio/mpeg' width='290' src='#: MediaLocation #'></audio>
   }
   else{
      <text>&nbsp; #: Description # </text>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment GyS. The @ inside the code blocks were my futile attempt in effort of trying to determine what the error meant. I modified my code based on your recommendation and no longer receive either of the other errors but am now getting "Parser Error Message: Inline markup blocks (@<p>Content</p>) cannot be nested.  Only one level of inline markup is allowed." in the else block using @: Any ideas what that means? I understand your explanation of its use but the error doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.aspnetwiki.com/telerik-mvc:nested-container-controls-and-razor-helper Looks like your are nesting tags like <text>.

Comment: If I am its not immediately obvious. But I'll definitely try the alternative approach provided in your link. Thanks.